# Undefined constant 'App\Http\Controllers\App\ClassName' Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a class call VSE, and I have more than **50** functions in there.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Request, Cache, App\Helper;


class VSE {

    .
    .
    .
    .

}
```

---

I want to list all of those functions.

I've tried

```
dd(get_class_methods(App\VSE));
```

I kept getting

```
Undefined constant 'App\Http\Controllers\App\VSE'
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: `use App\VSE` or `dd(get_class_methods(\App\VSE::class));`

Comment: Nope no luck. I got diff error now `Undefined constant 'App\VSE'`

Comment: You got me to the right direction. With this `dd(get_class_methods('\App\VSE'));` It's working now. :D

Comment: my bad, I forgot the `::class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, you need to import the `\App\VSE` class. You can do it with `use App\VSE` or you can specify the full path of the class: `\App\VSE`.

To retrieve the fully qualified name of class you can use the Class name resolution via `::class`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\VSE;

dd(get_class_methods(VSE::class));
```